# How do I set the default value to something in the same class?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a simple class called "BlockChain" where I store the head of the blockchain, the tail of the blockchain, and some other functions. Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Block.h"

class BlockChain {
  private:
  Block* head;
  Block* tail;
  public:
  BlockChain();
  void addBlock(int, std::string = "null-user");
  void displayChain(Block* = head);
  ~BlockChain();
};
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
./BlockChain.h:11:30: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'head'
  void displayChain(Block* = head);
```

I've tried replacing `head` with `this->head` but it just creates a similar error:

```
./BlockChain.h:11:30: error: invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static
      member function
  void displayChain(Block* = this->head);
```

Finally I tried making the `head` static, but that broke the rest of the program as I need to change `head` when adding new blocks. Please help, any ideas are appreciated.

EDIT: I have also tried making the function static, it doesn't work either.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `void displayChain(Block* = this->head);`?

Comment: You cannot do this, as it is explicitly forbidden by the C++ standard. There are possible workarounds, such as having the default be a null pointer and checking at the beginning of the function to replace it with `head` in that case

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says, you can't use a non-static member as a default argument.

Just make the default argument `nullptr` and in the first line of the implementation of `displayChain(...)` test for null and if it is `null` assign `head` to the argument, e.g.

```
class BlockChain {
    ...
    void displayChain(Block* block = nullptr);
    ...
};


void BlockChain::displayChain(Block* block) {
    if (!block) {
        block = head;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the variants already using a null pointer default argument, you could use *overloading*.

For example you could have one overload taking an argument *without* default value. Then one overload taking no argument, which calls the other overload passing `head` as argument:

```
void displayChain(Block* block);

void displayChain()
{
    displayChain(head);
}
```

Using overloads like this with an inline defined "default" function (the one taking no argument) makes it very easy to see what's really happens if no argument is passed, and exactly what will be used.

Answer (score 0):

This actually isn't possible. Workarounds such as making the default null and then checking in the function itself are the only way to solve this problem.